# i have this error The getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers

this is my code, i don't have a variable called value
this is my function from the database:

```
 getMarker() async {
//  List list = List();
String myUrl = "http://10.25.20.30:5000/api/markers";
var response = await http.get(myUrl,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',

    });

return response.body;
```

and it looks like this my response body : [{"log":"-7.939147","lag":"32.222754"},{"log":"-8.004948","lag":"31.621737"},{"log":"-8.017168","lag":"31.636198"}]

and this is the code to get markers from my json file

```
  Future<String> loadString() async =>     
    await databaseHelper.getMarker();  
    List<Marker> allMarkers = [];             

   void initState() {                        

   super.initState();                      
   _future = loadString();                 
   }
```

here i want to build my markers:

```
       return Container(                                                                                                                        
  height: MediaQuery                                                                                                                     
      .of(context)                                                                                                                       
      .size                                                                                                                              
      .height,                                                                                                                           
  width: MediaQuery                                                                                                                      
      .of(context)                                                                                                                       
      .size                                                                                                                              
      .width,                                                                                                                            


  child:  FutureBuilder(                                                                                                                 
    future:  _future,                                                                                                                    
     builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {                                                                                        
if (!snapshot.hasData) {                                                                                                                 
return CircularProgressIndicator();                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                        
   List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);                                                                                 

    allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {                                                                                              
            return Marker(                                                                                                               

                position: LatLng(double.parse(element['log']),double.parse(element['lag'])));                                             
          }).toList();                                                                                                                   
    return GoogleMap(                                                                                                                    
mapType: MapType.normal,                                                                                                                 
initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(                                                                                                   
target: LatLng(double.parse(userLocation.latitude.toString()),                                                                           
double.parse(userLocation.longitude.toString())), zoom: 12),                                                                              
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {                                                                                         
_controller.complete(controller);                                                                                                        
},                                                                                                                                       
markers:Set.from(allMarkers),                                                                                                            


);                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                        
  )                                                                                                                                       
);
```

}

i don't know where is the problem, since i don't have any value called "value" , pllz guys help me i need it ....

Comment: Can you post the complete logs related to this error?

Comment: -I/flutter ( 4113): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4113): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building GoogleMap(dirty, state: _GoogleMapState#f7247):
I/flutter ( 4113): The getter 'value' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4113): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4113): Tried calling: value

Comment: Okay is there no stack trace pointing to a particular line number? That could help debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this happend to me a lot, and every time that happened i was **passing** a **null** **argument** in one of my **functions**.

> best way is to start the **debugger** and start looking for **values** that
>   **should not be null**.

i would say check your **allMarkers List**.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone will have the same problem...

I had exactly the same issue until I added markerId to my Marker() constructor. In my case I had a unique string for each marker:

markers.add(Marker(
markerId: MarkerId(e['sid']),
position: LatLng(
e['lat'],
e['lon'],
)));